# Script for calling action-result that run incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a controller and I make two action-results inside

```
    public ActionResult ProductSearch(string term)
    {
        // Get Products from database
        InvoiceDBEntities db = new InvoiceDBEntities();
        var myproducts = (from E in db.Products
                          orderby E.Product ascending
                          select E.Product.Trim());

        return this.Json(myproducts.Where(t => t.Contains(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult DetailsFetch(string term)
    {
        InvoiceDBEntities db = new InvoiceDBEntities();
        var mydetails = (from E in db.Products
                          orderby E.Product ascending
                          select new
                          {
                              Product = E.Product.Trim(),
                              Price = E.Price.ToString(),
                              UM = E.UM
                          }).ToArray();

        return this.Json(mydetails.Where(t => t.Product.Contains(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and in view the corresponding script

```
        //auto complete products
        $('#itemName').autocomplete(
        {
            source: '/Invoices/ProductSearch'
        });
        //prefill some inputs
        $("#UM").focus(function () {
            var MySelection = $("#itemName").val().trim();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { term: MySelection },
                url: "/Invoices/DetailsFetch/",
                dataType: "json",

                succes: function (data) {
                    $("#UM").val(data.UM);
                    $("#rate").val(data.Price);
                },

                error: function () {
                    //Manage errors if any
                }
            });
        });

        $("#itemName").blur(function () {
            var MySelection = $("#itemName").val().trim();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { term: MySelection },
                url: "/Invoices/DetailsFetch/",
                dataType: "json",

                succes: function (data) {
                    $("#UM").val(data.UM);
                    $("#rate").val(data.Price);
                },
                error: function () {
                    //Manage errors if any
                }
            });
        });
        //
```

The first part (autocomplete) works fine. Now I want that on entering next input in my form (or any other event suitable) to execute the next action-result and pre-fill the relevant inputs in form with data that I obtained.
I can see result in browser, so the action-result works well, but none of concerned inputs is updated.
The response that I see in browser when I enter the next input (by mouse click or keyboard [tab]) is:

```
[{"Product":"Serviciu de dezvoltare aplicatie WEB","Price":"1000.00","UM":"Buc."}]
```

I used a similar concept in another part of my application with only difference that the event was a button click, and there all works fine, the relevant inputs where pre-filled with data from json response.

What I can do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response looks like an array with one item. So get the first item and use the property values

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.length)
    {
      var item =data[0]; //Get first item in the array
      $("#UM").val(item .UM);
      $("#rate").val(item .Price);
   }
},
```

But it is possible that your array may have more than one item because you are doing `Contains` method call to get the subset of items. But if you are interested in getting one single item's details, I suggest you pass the unique id (`ProductId` ?) to the server and get exactly the one record which matches that id. So instead of an array you will be returning a single object. In that case you can use your old code.3

Contains method will return true if there is the term you are passing is a substring of the colleciton. For example, If you have a product with name "MotorCar" and another with "Car", when you send "car" as the term value, Your where condition is going to return both the records. So you probably do not want to use the `Contains` method.

Assuming your ProductName's are unique, You can directly check the ProductName exactly match with the term your are sending.

```
public ActionResult DetailsFetch(string term)
{
    var db = new InvoiceDBEntities();
    var item = (from E in db.Products
                      orderby E.Product ascending
                      where E.Product 
                             .Equals(term,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                      select new
                      {
                          Product = E.Product.Trim(),
                          Price = E.Price.ToString(),
                          UM = E.UM
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
    if(item!=null)
    {
       return Json(new {status="success",details= item }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new {status="error"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now in your success event handler you simply need to check the response json and use the details as needed

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.status===="success")
    {          
      $("#UM").val(data.details.UM);
      $("#rate").val(data.details.Price);
    }
},
```

Also you do not need to listen to the blur / focus events on the other textbox, You can use the `select` event on the autocomplete to make your second ajax call to get the details.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var term = ui.item.label;
     // make the call here
}
```

Take a look at [How to make another ajax call upon selection of autocomplete text field value in ASP.NET MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753808/how-to-make-another-ajax-call-upon-selection-of-autocomplete-text-field-value-in/35757501#35757501) for detailed sample code

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (with only change that I made a new action-result instead "DetailsGet"), but still does nothing. The response is there ({"status":"success","details":{"Product":"Serviciu de gazduire aplicatie web","Price":"30.00","UM":"Luna"}}) but nothing is updated. I did not yet tried the very last suggestion because I did not understand very well how to do. My autocomplete is somehow different.

Comment: Check the spelling of your `success` event ! It was wrong in your question :)

Comment: Now is working, but still don't understand yet your last advice and it seems  exactly what I want.

Comment: You can use the select event in the auto complete call insted of listening to the `blur` of the input. See the link in posted

Comment: I have tried, but at least is not displaying the result of autocomplete (I see the response in browser) on page. Maybe I am doing something wrong, don't know.

Comment: Can you create dot net fiddle and (static hard coded data) and share with me ?

Comment: I can do it sunday. No I am not in town.